# How to upload multiple files in Flutter using Dio and permit only a specific number of files and specific size of the file?

Tags: flutter, filepicker.io, dio

I have been trying to pick multiple files but the user only gets to pick 4 files not more than that. And there should be a restriction on the size of the file too.

The documents have been updated and I couldn't find a single tutorial with an updated one.
I even thought of using multi_image_picker but that is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Uint8List fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes  (get the files sizes from the results and throw an error if it exceeds the max size)