# How to upload multiple files server using dio and file_picker package,

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker.io, dio

I want to upload multiple files using dio and file_picker.

I know I will have to pick different types of files like this:
List files = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(
type: FileType.IMAGE); (outdated now)

Kindly help me with the updated version on how to write it for multiple files and send it to the backend using formdata.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload multiple images/files in Flutter using Dio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263840/how-to-upload-multiple-images-files-in-flutter-using-dio)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```dart
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if(result != null) {
   List<MultipartFile> files = result.paths.map((path) => MultipartFile.fromFileSync(path)).toList();  
   var dio = Dio();
   var formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'name': 'wendux', // other parameter may you need to send
    'age': 25, // other parameter may you need to send
    'files': files,
  });

  var response = await dio.post('url', data: formData); 
  // check response status code
  if(response.statusCode == 200){
     // it's uploaded
  }

} else {
   // User canceled the picker
}
```

Comment: Can you answer this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67743402/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-flutter-using-dio-and-permit-only-a-specific-num